Was Jesus sent into a body of sinful flesh despite never sinning?
These passages seem to indicate that when Jesus incarnated into human flesh, that his flesh was just like our flesh which was cursed with sin. Would this explain how Jesus defeated sin and death on the cross; by wearing sin and experiencing death himself despite being completely innocent?
Romans 8:3-4 ESV

For God has done what the Law, weakened by the flesh, could not do. By
sending His own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh and for sin, He
condemned sin in the flesh, in order that the righteous requirement of
the Law might be fulfilled in us, who walk not according to the flesh
but according to the Spirit.

2 Corinthians 5:21 ESV

For our sake He made Him to be sin who knew no sin, so that in Him we
might become the righteousness of God.

Hebrews 4:15 ESV

For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our
weaknesses, but One who in every respect has been tempted as we are,
yet did not sin.

Romans 6:6 ESV

We know that our old self was crucified with Him in order that the
body of sin might be brought to nothing, so that we would no longer be
enslaved to sin.

1 Peter 4:1 ESV

Since therefore Christ suffered in the flesh, arm yourselves with the
same way of thinking, for whoever has suffered in the flesh has ceased
from sin.

Hebrews 2:14-18 ESV

Since therefore the children share in flesh and blood, He Himself
likewise partook of the same things, that through death He might
destroy the one who has the power of death, that is, the devil, and
deliver all those who through fear of death were subject to lifelong
slavery. For surely it is not angels that He helps, but He helps the
offspring of Abraham.
Therefore He had to be made like His brothers in
every respect, so that He might become a merciful and faithful high
priest in the service of God, to make propitiation for the sins of the
people. For because He Himself has suffered when tempted, He is able
to help those who are being tempted.


This is an EXTREMELY theological question about which there has been furious debate for 2000 years - and you expect to solve it in one question???  Some of these verses say the opposite of what you think they are saying.

Dottard - How could Jesus have conquered sin if he didn't have it in his human flesh?

If Jesus were sinful in any way, He would have need a savior Himself - but He was sinless and pure, holy and blameless.

Dottard - That's exactly right. Jesus was sinless and pure, holy and blameless, because He resisted his sinful flesh 100% without failure. Likewise, we must be without sin and pure, holy and blameless before God; and this occurs through faith and obedience to Jesus Christ the conqueror. Jesus defeated sin so that we can defeat sin and join Him in the Resurrection.

It might be better to ask a more basic question first:  Is flesh (σάρξ) sinful in and of itself?  Basically, is 'flesh' and 'sin' synonymous?  Personally, I hold to the idea that σάρξ signifies 'corruptibility'.  The idea of "potential corruption" might be more along the lines of what you're asking here.  But, that's the reason I'm saying that "what is flesh (σάρξ)?" is a more basic question.

MikeSangrey - Don't ever entertain the twisted notion that human flesh is not cursed with sin. If one does, they are arrogant and deny the work of Christ on the cross.

One inherits from his father.   Jesus thus could be physically 100% human but have no sin. Tye life that animated the man Jesus was from God through the holy spirt, not from an imperfect human sperm donor.

Kris - Jesus did not ever sin, but he did have sin in his flesh, that is, Jesus wore Adam's sinful flesh upon himself yet never gave into the temptations that are usual for the flesh. He lived in the Spirit for God instead. That's how Jesus defeated sin; he destroyed sin in his flesh by taking it to the cross as the atonement for our sin, freeing us from our lives in the flesh and to walk new according to the Spirit.

A good part of my reason for suggesting a better question, "Is flesh sinful in and of itself" is what Paul says in Phil. 3:4,6 (YLT).  "though I also have [cause of] trust in flesh. If any other one doth think to have trust in flesh, I more;...according to righteousness that is in law becoming blameless!"  Paul has confidence "in the flesh" and backs it up with a blameless adherence to the Law.  Was adhering to the Law sinful?  It certainly didn't justify.  But, was it sinful?  My suggested question gets at an assumption you're making.

MikeSangrey - Read Romans 7:18 and 8:13! Flesh and sin are always correlated.

@Dottard, If Jesus were sinful in any way, He would have need a savior Himself Jesus did need a savior. See Hebrews 5:7.

Let us take these texts one at a time:
Romans 8:3-4 ESV

For God has done what the Law, weakened by the flesh, could not do. By
sending His own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh and for sin,
He condemned sin in the flesh, in order that the righteous requirement
of the Law might be fulfilled in us, who walk not according to the
flesh but according to the Spirit.

Thus, this text explicitly says that Jesus flesh was like ours but it was not sinful.
2 Corinthians 5:21 ESV

For our sake He made Him to be sin who knew no sin, so that in Him
we might become the righteousness of God.

That is, Jesus knew no sin but took our sins on Himself as the atonement for all.  That is, the only sin found in Jesus was our sin, NOT His own.
Hebrews 4:15 ESV

For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our
weaknesses, but One who in every respect has been tempted as we are,
yet did not sin.

The last phrase of this translation is inaccurate it should be: "without sin" - the difference is important; Jesus was sinless not only because He committed no sin but had no tendency to sin (unlike David as per Ps 51:3 as opposed to Jesus who was declared "Holy from birth", Luke 1:35.)
Romans 6:6 ESV

We know that our old self was crucified with Him in order that the
body of sin might be brought to nothing, so that we would no longer be
enslaved to sin.

This says nothing about the nature of Christ.
1 Peter 4:1 ESV

Since therefore Christ suffered in the flesh, arm yourselves with the
same way of thinking, for whoever has suffered in the flesh has ceased
from sin.

Again, this says nothing about the nature of Christ.
Hebrews 2:14-18 ESV

Since therefore the children share in flesh and blood, He Himself
likewise partook of the same things [ie, flesh and blood: Doh!], that
through death He might destroy the one who has the power of death,
that is, the devil, and deliver all those who through fear of death
were subject to lifelong slavery. For surely it is not angels that He
helps, but He helps the offspring of Abraham.

This simply says that Jesus was fully human with flesh and blood - again, this says nothing about the nature of Christ.
I give the last word to Hebrews 7:26 -

Such a high priest [ie, Jesus] truly befits us—One who is holy,
innocent, undefiled, set apart from sinners, and exalted above the
heavens.

Jesus was both sinless and undefiled by sin, ie, had no sinful human nature.  If He did, He would have needed a Saviour Himself.
APPENDIX - Nature of Sin
Let us examine the comments in 1 John 1:8, 10 -

V8: If we say we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is
not in us.

This text says that sin (a noun) is a state of being and thus we 9unlike Jesus) are all sinful

If we say we have not sinned (a verb), we make Him out to be a
liar, and His word is not in us.

This text says that we are all sinners because we have all sinned, ie, done wrong things, unlike Jesus who never sinned even in thought.

I wonder how Jesus could be tempted of the devil if he never sinned, even in thought. It would hardly be a temptation in that case.  I suppose my real question is this: is it a sin to consider sinning?

@DanFefferman - Jesus certainly never committed any sins, but I think that Jesus certainly had sin in his flesh, because he knew our sufferings and destroyed sin in the flesh by killing it on the cross.

@DanFefferman - as you would be presumably aware, theologians distinguish between innocent humanity and sinful humanity - it is not sinful to be hungry, so the Devil waited until Jesus was hungry to tempt Him to create food.  Such a temptation was befitting Jesus because we could not do such a thing but Jesus could!

@ Dan Fefferman - Interesting point. But it depends how "consider" is defined. If it means that one "mentally sees an offered action as a sin, and recalls the pros and cons if ever yielded to, and makes a willful decision to abstain", then there is no mental sin involved.  If on the other hand, "consider" means thinking about yielding because he sees pleasure in it, then it would be sinning. Because Jesus dealt with this approach when He said that "If a man lusts in his heart after...he has committed the sin already in his heart!" Thank you for all your insightful answers on SE.

If He did, He would have needed a Saviour Himself. Jesus did need a savior. See Hebrews 5:7.

Jesus did not inherit a sinful flesh, but he assumed or took on a sinful flesh.
That is, the sinful flesh was not passed down to him from Adam, but God gave it to him.
For him to be a merciful high priest, he has to be made like us in every respect, including taking on a sinful flesh.
It should be noted however that, Jesus did not yield in to the desires of the flesh.
And because we are joined to him by faith,we can equally overcome the desires of the flesh.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Jesus was born of a woman, so that is the means he would have inherited the sinful flesh.

Imagine our body as garments, pristine white at the beginning of our lives, yet destined to endure without ever being removed. Can we maintain this purity until the very end?
It's crucial to understand that it is not the flesh itself that is inherently sinful, but rather its susceptibility to succumb to sinful moments, akin to how a white garment inevitably attracts dust and dirt.
When the Word became flesh, Jesus' temptations showcased that the flesh can indeed triumph over sin through unwavering faith in God. His responses to the devil, all prefaced with "It is written" (Matt 4:4, 4:7 and 4:10), underscored His steadfast obedience to God's commandments. His victory over temptation paved "a new and living way" (Heb 10:20) for humanity, enabling us to "draw near to God with a sincere heart and with the full assurance that faith brings" (Heb 10:22)
In Revelation 3:4-5, we see a few people in Sardis who demonstrated this possibility.

4 Yet you have a few people in Sardis who have not soiled their clothes. They will walk with me, dressed in white, for they are worthy. 5 The one who is victorious will, like them, be dressed in white. I will never blot out the name of that person from the book of life, but will acknowledge that name before my Father and his angels. (NIV)


Paul said that there is sin in our flesh, as it is cursed. This means that it flesh gives us the desire to sin, even before Adam ate from the tree. Flesh is weak, but the Spirit is strong.

@JoshuaB - You are correct in most regards, though I disagree with your characterization of describing the fresh as sinful. Money itself is not evil, it's the malicious intentions behind its use that are problematic. Similarly, the flesh is not inherently sinful, it is the surrender to shameful lusts that leads to sin. It's important not to label something neutral, like the fresh, as sinful. After all, Jesus demonstrated that the fresh can be used in a holy manner.

Sacrificial Lamb Perhaps the illustration of the sacrificial Lamb both in the O.T. and in the N.T. would bring clarity to the riddle of the Incarnation of Christ:

The next day John saw Jesus coming toward him and said, "Behold (look), the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world!" (John 1:29)

It is true that in the process of the Incarnation Jesus was robed in flesh. But recall that this was not a usual conception. The birth was actuated by the power of the Holy Spirit, not a marriage union. Thus Christ gained a fleshly body, but did not inherit the sinful, fallen state of humanity.
Without Blemish Being in the flesh, Jesus experienced the same kind of temptations known to man, but He never engaged in any of those sins. [He also experienced hunger, thirst, fatigue, emotions, etc. as well, by the way.]
And this was important because a major requirement of any "substitutionary sacrifice" under the Mosaic Law had to be spotless and without blemish. Jesus was to be this "sacrificial Lamb" in the N.T, fulfilling the symbolism of the O.T. (See Hebrews; types and shadows.) And He did meet this requirement! He was without blemish...without sin. Jesus was sent into a body of human flesh...but not sinful flesh. (He did not inherit a sin nature from Joseph.)

The animals you choose must be year-old males without defect (blemish)... (Exodus 12:5)


Then say to the Israelites, "Take a male goat for a sin offering, a calf and a lamb---both a year old and without defect (blemish)  for a burnt offering. (Leviticus 9:3, 14:10, 23:12)


There he is to present his offerings to the LORD, a year old male lamb without defect (blemish) for a burnt offering...(Numbers 6:14)

Imputed When the verses say, "He became sin..." they are speaking figuratively. The sins of all mankind were imputed onto Jesus while on the cross. He did not die for sins He committed. Recall how the priests laid hands on the Scapegoat imputing the sins of Israel onto it, as another example. The goat was spotless, but when the hands were laid on it, it represented sin---became sin---and was destroyed in that condition. Thus Jesus too.

When Aaron has finished making atonement for the most holy place, the Tent of Meeting, and the altar, he shall bring forward the live goat. He is to lay both hands on the head of the live goat and confess over it all the wickedness and rebellion of the Israelites---all their sins---and put them on the goat's head. (Leviticus 16:21)

There is no controversy in designating Jesus as the sinless Lamb who was sacrificed for all our sins that were "imputed upon Him". Just as Adam, when without a sinful nature (!) was tempted to sin...so Jesus---the second Adam without a sinful nature---was tempted to sin, but refused all temptation. [Note: Adam was tempted before his Fall.]
And this made Him qualified to be a spotless, without blemish, propitiation and substitutionary sacrificial Lamb.

For you know that it was not with perishable things such as silver or gold that you were redeemed....but with the precious blood of Christ, a Lamb without blemish or defect.

The fact that Jesus without the stain of a sinful nature---pristine character in essence---was willing to experience the horrendous, excruciating, trauma of vile sin dumped all over Him (imputed on Him) for our eternal benefit, is great reason for every believer to exult in grateful praise and adoration to this Lamb of God!!!

I disagree, because to gain a fleshly mortal body after the fall is to gain with it the fallen sinful curse that permeates it. When Christ came into the world, into mortal flesh, he also wore the curse of sin that permeates that flesh. Despite this, He never once fell into sin when his flesh tempted him. That's how Jesus redeemed us from this world: He died in our sinful flesh despite being innocent so that God saw fit to resurrect Him as the first-fruit of the great harvest to come for all who believe and follow in Christ's example.

The lamb "without blemish" is the fact that Jesus was totally innocent as He was always living by the Spirit, not that the flesh body that Jesus walked in didn't have the sinful curse of Adam within it.

@ Joshua B - Consider; As "the second Adam", Jesus was tempted like Adam was tempted before his fall! A "sinless nature" can be tempted just as a "sinful nature" can be tempted.  Adam showed that.  Notice that the Bible said that Jesus became a curse (on the cross, for cursed is every one who hangs on a tree) not that He was born a cursed man.  Thanks for raising up such an important question! Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul.

ray grant - I get your point, but you miss the crucial point: Jesus had to resist the draw of sin in the flesh, just like how we have to resist the draw if sin in our flesh. If Jesus was not like us in every way, then he couldn't have shown us the way to eternity by becoming like us in every way and teaching us how to live lives separate from the sinful flesh and in the Spirit instead. Furthermore, Jesus destroyed sin by killing the sin in his flesh, and therefore also in our flesh, on the cross.
